# Compare date with a specific one and DateTime to string in Twig

Tags: php, twig

1. How can I compare two dates in Twig when the first one comes from the dababase and the second is clear - 2012-12-31? 
   I tried  with

   ```
   {% if  dom.dueDate|date('Y-m-d') > 2012-12-31 %}
   ```

   but I don't get the result I want. :(
2. I have a DateTime field but I couldn't find a filter for DateTime in Twig and when I use `|date('Y-m-d')` it prints only the date without the hour :(

I would be really happy and grateful if someone helps me to solve the problems!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try timestamps for comparison
:

```
{% if dom.dueDate|date('U') > '2012-12-31'|date('U') %}
```

and this to add hours, minutes and seconds

```
{{ dom.dueDate|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}
```

Comment: Ooh thank you so much! You can't imagine how grateful I am. I searched for both of them but couldn't find anything. Now everything works corectly! Once again thank you very much!

Comment: Happy new year edition `{% if 'now'|date('U') > '2013-12-20'|date('U') and 'now'|date('U') < '2014-01-09'|date('U') %}` :-)

Comment: Consider your timezone when you use "U" parameter. Because it refers to unix timestamp at UTC. Your city may be on different UTC timezone. UTC+2 or UTC-1 etc...

Comment: Cheers @AlexeyB. the 'now' function is handy!

Comment: Awsm thx heaps! Really helped me.

Answer (score 12):

As of twig 1.6+, the correct way of comparing dates [according to the official docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/date.html) is using the `date` function:

```
{% if dom.dueDate > date('2012-12-31') %}
```

Comment: @RaymondA I'm not sure about that because the OP actually asked explicit after comparing DateTime with DateTime and not Date with Date so the accepted answer contains the correct approaches

Comment: @thex I preserved the data used in the answer, but the code is actually using DateTime objects. The date "twig" method is just a wrapper to the PHP one, so just have to add the hour if you want to.

Comment: @giosh94mhz You are right your expression evaluates to the correct result asked in 1.)...forget my post. But that was also not what I meant I stated it completely wrong. I meant that the accepted answer takes the DateTime format into account what was asked in 2.) whether yours only covers 1.) - the comparison. But nevermind, both answers contain useful information.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if date(dom.dueDate) > date(2012-12-31) %}
```