# How to compare dates in twig

Tags: twig

I have the following twig template

```
   {% for id,value in item.attributes %}
      {% set attribute_details = getAttributeSet(id) %}
         ID: {{id}}<br>
         VALUE: {{value.sec|date("d/m/Y")}}<br>
         TYPE: {{data}}<br>
         LABEL: {{attribute_details.label}}<br>
   {% endfor %}
```

resulting in the following text:

```
ID: 607ecae15fb8e0c3c2d7ca02
VALUE: 19/05/2021
TYPE: 
LABEL: scadenza_offerta
```

How can I check wether VALUE is grater than 19/05/2021? And How I can hide the text otherwise?

I have try this code but it does not work:

```
{% if VALUE == '19/05/2021' %}
    work
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What is in `value.sec`?

Comment: without value.sec VALUE: 0.000000001619560800...i think other format of date

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare date with a specific one and DateTime to string in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774520/compare-date-with-a-specific-one-and-datetime-to-string-in-twig)

Comment: Ok but how I can insert control for data? because i don't understand.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I don't understand how to make it work :(

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774520/compare-date-with-a-specific-one-and-datetime-to-string-in-twig)

```html
{% if date(value.sec) > date('19/05/2021') %}
    work
{% endif %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/0bj043)

Comment: and if I want to check if current date is expired? How I can?

Comment: You can get the current date with the string `NOW`, e.g. `{% if date(value.sec) > date('NOW') %}`

Comment: No not current date but date into "VALUE: 19/05/2021"