# Date and Time Greater/Less Than Comparisons not working for me in Timber/Twig

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, timber

Having some difficulties with my if/else statements recognizing my date and time greater or less than properly in my custom WordPress theme using ACF.

I think I may have it narrowed down to that is comparing strings instead of timestamps from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642417/php-date-time-greater-than-today/32642436) but am baffled how to output that properly in twig? Here would be an example of what I currently have:

```
{% set dateandtime = fn('wp_date', "F j, Y g:i a") %}
{% set salestart = post.sale_start | date("F j, Y g:i a") %}
{% set saleend = post.sale_end | date("F j, Y g:i a") %}
```

and then:

```
{% if salestart >= dateandtime %}
  <p>This sale will start {{salestart}}.</p> 
  {% elseif dateandtime >= salestart and dateandtime <= saleend %}
    <p>This sale will end {{saleend}}.</p>
  {% elseif dateandtime >= saleend %} 
      <p>Sorry this sale has ended as of {{saleend}}.</p>
{% endif %}
```

I think my issue is that its comparing strings instead of real datestamps but not quite sure what to do differently?

```
{{ dump(dateandtime) }} ouputs: ~src\Extension\DebugExtension.php:70:string 'July 31, 2021 2:43 pm' 
{{ dump(salestart) }} ouputs: ~src\Extension\DebugExtension.php:70:string 'August 4, 2021 9:00 pm' 
{{ dump(saleend) }} ouputs: ~src\Extension\DebugExtension.php:70:string 'August 6, 2021 5:00 pm'
```

I tried fiddling with `|format_datetime()` [from Twig Docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/format_datetime.html) but didn't have much success? A clear explanation will be much appreciated as I am still a noob at this :)
~ Thank-you!

Comment: Use the function `date` not the filter `{% set salestart = date(datepost.sale_start) %}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare date with a specific one and DateTime to string in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774520/compare-date-with-a-specific-one-and-datetime-to-string-in-twig)

Comment: Thank-you, but how would I format it for the wp_date in wordpress `{% set dateandtime = fn('wp_date', "F j, Y g:i a") %}` because this also just outputs in string

Comment: I tried this but it won't work `{% set dateandtime = fn('wp_date', 'date') %}` and `{% set dateandtime = date(wp_date) %}`

Comment: I could do this but `{% set dateandtime = date(now) %}` then its off by -4:00 hrs I would like `dateandtime ` to be the WordPress time.

Comment: Okay I think this may work here: `{% set dateandtime = fn('wp_date', 'U') %}` feel free to comment if there is a better way and many thanks again to @DarkBee for your help!